# fscanf QT widget C++

Tags: file-io, scanf

I got problem with fscanf function while reading camera parameters file. I'm using QT 4.7, writing QT widget application. I'm getting segmentation fault when executing first fscanf statement. But when I execute code in console application project it works good.

Here is part of my code:

```
struct parametry_kamery
           {
            float cc[2],fc[2],alpha_c,kc[5];
            int D,al;
           };
    parametry_kamery kam_par;

void Widget::readParameters(parametry_kamery* kam_par)
{

 FILE *fi;
 char buf[255];
 float cc1=0,cc2=0;

 fi=fopen("Camera parameters.cfg", "r");

 if(!fi)
 {
  QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Can't read file"),tr("Error"));
  return;
 }

 while('\n'!=fgetc(fi));
 fscanf(fi,"%s %s %s %f %f",buf,buf,buf,&cc1,&cc2);

kam_par->fc[0] = cc1;
kam_par->fc[1] = cc2;

 fclose(fi);
}
```

I'm calling function readParameters(&kam_par);

And here is the content of file:

```
Parametry_wewnętrzne_kamery
Focal_Length:                    fc =  1079.33793   1181.44679  ± [ 2.44878   2.52105]
Principal_point:                 cc =  378.95649   245.99109  ± [ 3.48032   2.99878 ]
Skew:                       alpha_c =  0.00000  ±  0.00000     => angle of pixel axes = 90.00000 ± 0.00000 degrees
Distortion:                      kc =  -0.13666   -0.01830   -0.00070   0.00134  0.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first fscanf is reading 3 strings and then 2 floats. But your file seems to start with 4 strings before the 2 floats. The first 4 strings are:

```
Parametry_wewnętrzne_kamery
Focal_Length:
fc
=
```

And by the way, when you are using Qt, it would be much easier (and less error-prone) to use Qt's file functions (QFile and QTextStream) and QString and its conversions functions.

Comment: But why in console application this works well? I added one more string and had float in buf so it didn't work. I forgot that i have warnings:
format '%s' expects type 'char*', but argument 3 has type 'char (*)[250]'

Comment: I'm new in QT and didn't find such easy way to get those floats as fscanf gives me

Comment: Ah, that might be the actual problem. You should give `buf` as a parameter, not `&buf`.

Comment: Removed it, I don't have warnings but still get segmentation fault

Comment: Break the problem to smaller parts. First read only one parameter and print it. When that works, add second parameter, then third parameter and so on until you find where the problem is.

Comment: I did as you said and find out that error appears when i'm trying set the values of structure. I've tried to pass the pointer to the structure and set the values like this:
kam_par->fc[0] = cc1;
i think the error is that i can't write fc[0] but dont know how to make it good

Comment: Show your new code. In the question `kam_par` is not a pointer, but in your comment it is.

Comment: post edited, I left only one fscanf if that one will be properly made i can easy edit the others

Comment: I still think you should have 4 string parameters in the scanf. The only reason I can see why the code would fail is that the fscanf has not read valid floats. When you run your code in the debugger, what are the values of the cc1 and cc2? After fscanf print _everything_ you have read (or inspect the variables in the debugger) and see if the values are what you are expecting.

Comment: the values are correct i checked them in the debugger, the first line is ignored because it doesn't fit to the model "string string string float float". I didn't write it clearly, now error appears not in fscanf (it works good) but in next line: kam_par->fc[0] = cc1;

Comment: Well, I can't find the bug. What you could try is to set the value of kam_par->fc[0] in the beginning of the readParameters function. If it works, then fscanf is the culprit. It is _very_ easy to trash the memory with scanf functions. That's why I recommended using Qt's alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the function, now it takes structure by value and return structure, I know that it require more memory but works well for now. I will try to fix the version with pointer.
Great thanks for your help Roku.

```
Widget::parametry_kamery Widget::readParameters(parametry_kamery kam_par)
{

 FILE *fi;
 char buf[255];

 fi=fopen("Camera parameters.cfg", "r");

 if(!fi)
 {
  QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Błąd odczytu pliku konfiguracyjnego"),tr("Error"));
  return parametry_kamery::parametry_kamery();
 }

 while('\n'!=fgetc(fi));

 fscanf(fi,"%s %s %s %f %f",buf,buf,buf,&kam_par.fc[0],&kam_par.fc[1]);

QMessageBox::information(this,buf,buf2);
 while('\n'!=fgetc(fi));
 fscanf(fi,"%s %s %s %f %f",buf,buf,buf,&kam_par.cc[0],&kam_par.cc[1]);

 while('\n'!=fgetc(fi));
 fscanf(fi,"%s %s %s %f",buf,buf,buf,&kam_par.alpha_c);

 while('\n'!=fgetc(fi));
 fscanf(fi,"%s %s %s %f %f %f %f %f",buf,buf,buf,&kam_par.kc[0],
       &kam_par.kc[1],&kam_par.kc[2],&kam_par.kc[3],&kam_par.kc[4]);

 while('\n'!=fgetc(fi));
 fscanf(fi,"%s %s %s %i",buf,buf,buf,&kam_par.D);

 while('\n'!=fgetc(fi));
 fscanf(fi,"%s %s %s %i",buf,buf,buf,&kam_par.al);

 fclose(fi);
 return kam_par;
}
```